# check Datareader is null or not

Tags: c#, sql-server, null, sqldatareader

Please see my below code, I am trying to read data from a table, if there are any rows in table which matches the condition then execute some lines of code and if there are no rows then execute other set of code.

when I execute this piece of code, its throwing an exception. "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"
any suggestion as to where exactly am going wrong.

```
public void Check_Last_RegNo()
    {
        try
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            con.Open();
            string ct = "SELECT Max(RegistrationNo) from tbl_StudentRegNo where (RegistrationNo Like'%" + label3.Text + "%')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(ct);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr[0]!=null && rdr[0]!=DBNull.Value)
            {

                int ii = 1;
                for (int max = 0; max < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; max++)
                {

                    label4.Text = ii.ToString("0000");
                    string concati = reg_no + label3.Text + label4.Text;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[max].Cells[2].Value = concati;
                    ii++;
                }


            }
            else
                {
                    while (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        label5.Text = (rdr[0]).ToString();
                        string lastregno = label5.Text;
                        string digits = lastregno.Substring(lastregno.Length - 4, 4);
                        label4.Text = digits.ToString();
                        int i = Convert.ToInt32(digits) + 1;
                        for (int max = 0; max < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; max++)
                        {

                            label4.Text = i.ToString("0000");
                            string concati = reg_no + label3.Text + label4.Text;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[max].Cells[2].Value = concati;
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }


        con.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mainly, you try to access `rdr[0]` *before* you call `rdr.HasRows`. But looking at this code, you never move onto the next row so you if you did get past this exception, you would get stuck in your `while` loop. Either change that to `if(rdr.Read())` or `while(rdr.Read())` to ensure the datareader moves to the first/next row

Comment: What is the datatype of RegistrationNO?

Comment: varchar(50), I am able to fetch the last record using MAX(RegistrationNo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to change my code a bit, and the exception was gone, change seems bit complicated but it worked. Here is the code.

```
try
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            con.Open();
            string ct = "SELECT Max(RegistrationNo) from tbl_StudentRegNo where (RegistrationNo Like'%" + lblshortcode.Text + "%')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(ct);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    lbllastregno.Text = (rdr[0]).ToString();
                    string lastregno = lbllastregno.Text;
                    if(rdr[0]!=DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        string current_serial_no = lastregno.Substring(lastregno.Length - 4, 4);
                        lblcurrentsno.Text = current_serial_no;
                        int next_serial_no = Convert.ToInt32(current_serial_no) + 1;
                        lblnextsno.Text = next_serial_no.ToString("0000");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbllastregno.Text = reg_no + lblshortcode.Text + lbldigitformat.Text;
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbllastregno.Text = reg_no + lblshortcode.Text + lbldigitformat.Text;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to check the reader values without verifying if it has any rows by using the if statement. This causes the Exception.

You can use reader.Read() to check and move the reader to the next row in one action.

If you need to check if the reader has Rows to execute an alternate flow, check for rdr.HasRows as the first condition.

```
if (rdr.HasRows) 
{
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                label5.Text = (rdr[0]).ToString();
                string lastregno = label5.Text;
                string digits = lastregno.Substring(lastregno.Length - 4, 4);
                label4.Text = digits.ToString();
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(digits) + 1;
                for (int max = 0; max < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; max++)
                {

                    label4.Text = i.ToString("0000");
                    string concati = reg_no + label3.Text + label4.Text;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[max].Cells[2].Value = concati;
                    i++;
                }
            }
}
else
            {
                int ii = 1;
                for (int max = 0; max < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; max++)
                {

                    label4.Text = ii.ToString("0000");
                    string concati = reg_no + label3.Text + label4.Text;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[max].Cells[2].Value = concati;
                    ii++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: a new exception is thrown "StartIndex cannot be less than zero."

Comment: @sirajahmed you must be getting that error on your substring operation. Check your lastregno length

Comment: string digits = lastregno.Substring(lastregno.Length - 4, 4);

Comment: @sirajahmed What is the length of the string lastregno? I suspect it is less than 4

Comment: basically all i want is, to check if datareader rdr is not null execute the while(rdr.Read()) part.

Comment: @sirajahmed The code does exactly that. Now you are getting a different error which has no relation to the datareader. It is because of an error in the way you are using substring.

Comment: lastregno gets its value from rdr [0]. if there is no data in the particular row, the cursor should jump to else part of the code. which is not happening in this case

Comment: @sirajahmed It is not null for sure, it has some value, can you debug and tell me what the value is

Comment: when debugged the statement, it returns true. which is basically wrong. it should return false as there are no rows in table which contains RegistrationNo Like Label3.text.

Answer (score 1):

Your first if statement don't makes sense. you can use if condition to check if any row found and read rows one by one, and you have to check if `rdr[0]` is not null then do operation on it. :

```
if (rdr.HasRows)  // check if any row found
        {
            while(rdr.Read())  // read all matched rows one by one
            {
                label5.Text = rdr[0] != DbNull.Value ? (rdr[0]).ToString() : string.Empty;
                string lastregno = label5.Text;
                string digits = lastregno.Substring(lastregno.Length - 4, 4);
                label4.Text = digits.ToString();
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(digits) + 1;
                for (int max = 0; max < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; max++)
                {

                    label4.Text = i.ToString("0000");
                    string concati = reg_no + label3.Text + label4.Text;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[max].Cells[2].Value = concati;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

`SqlDataReader` fetches row in a sequence one by one so for reading a row we have to call `rdr.Read()`, when we call it, it fetches one row, so by writing `while(rdr.Read())` we are saying that read records one by one until all records are processed.

When you call `rdr[0]` first without calling `rdr.Read()` it will obviously fail because there is no row being read which `rdr` hold.

Comment: a new exception "StartIndex cannot be less than zero"

Answer (score 1):

When you build an `SqlDataReader` with `ExecuteReader` the object returned is not positioned on the first record of the returned set of data (if any) so, before trying to access any field in the reader, you need to call `Read()` or `HasRows` The latter in case you just want to know if there are records, the first, in case you need to actually read the dataset returned. Your error is triggered by the fact that you try to use the Reader accessing `rdr[0]` before moving the Reader on the first record.

But you are complicating things, because, given this query:

```
string ct = "SELECT Max(RegistrationNo) ....";
```

then you have a null or just one line with one column. 
So the best method to call here is [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand(ct);
 cmd.Connection = con;
 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if(result != null)
 {
    // Now you have here your registration value as a string
    string maxRegistrationNo = result.ToString();

    // You could apply your logic to extract the required parts
    ....
    ....
 }
 else
 {
     // Your logic for a null return from your query
     ......
 }
```

As you can read from MSDN

> Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example,
>   an aggregate value) from a database. This requires less code than
>   using the ExecuteReader method, and then performing the operations
>   that you need to generate the single value using the data returned by
>   a SqlDataReader.

Comment: Bingo, but `label5.Text = (rdr[0]).ToString();` so this should probably be `result as string`?

Comment: @RGraham probably yes, still the remainder of this code is a bit unclear.